# QuickReturn ListView in an activity?difficulty in 2 views in an activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I am trying to use a QuickReturn ListView in an activity. The link given below uses a fragment do it.

> http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/quickreturn-listview/

I am stuck here:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
View mHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
```

I can't find an alternative. How can I change the above code so that it can be used in an activity?

Quick return ListView uses to different views and stitches them together. Then works upon them in a fragment. I can't do it in case of an activity.

Answer (score 0):

To get the the root view from inside activity use:

```
View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

To get inflater from inside activity use:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
```

Hope this help, please tell me if not.

Comment: I am facing same problem . Can you please tell me where to put these codes ?

Comment: @Kunu in activity onCreate

Comment: Can you please check my question. Its here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754635/how-to-implement-quickreturnlist-in-an-activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754635/how-to-implement-quickreturnlist-in-an-activity)