# How to implement QuickReturnList in an Activity?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

How to implement tabs, using activity for each tab. I found [this tutorial](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView) but it implemented with Fragments. [Here](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/quickreturn-listview/) is a video that show exactly what I want to do.

Here what I been trying to do:

**DefaultActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater  = (LayoutInflater) DefaultActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
        mHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        mQuickReturnView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sticky);
        mPlaceHolder = mHeader.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);



        mListView = (QuickReturnListView) getListView(); //showing class cast exception here

        mQuickReturnView.setText("Default");
        mListView.addHeaderView(mHeader);

        String[] array = new String[] { "Android", "Android", "Android",
                "Android", "Android", "Android", "Android", "Android",
                "Android", "Android", "Android", "Android", "Android",
                "Android", "Android", "Android" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);


        mListView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        mQuickReturnHeight = mQuickReturnView.getHeight();
                        mListView.computeScrollY();
                        mCachedVerticalScrollRange = mListView.getListHeight();
                    }
                });

        mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                mScrollY = 0;
                int translationY = 0;

                if (mListView.scrollYIsComputed()) {
                    mScrollY = mListView.getComputedScrollY();
                }

                int rawY = mPlaceHolder.getTop()
                        - Math.min(
                                mCachedVerticalScrollRange
                                        - mListView.getHeight(), mScrollY);

                switch (mState) {
                case STATE_OFFSCREEN:
                    if (rawY <= mMinRawY) {
                        mMinRawY = rawY;
                    } else {
                        mState = STATE_RETURNING;
                    }
                    translationY = rawY;
                    break;

                case STATE_ONSCREEN:
                    if (rawY < -mQuickReturnHeight) {
                        mState = STATE_OFFSCREEN;
                        mMinRawY = rawY;
                    }
                    translationY = rawY;
                    break;

                case STATE_RETURNING:
                    translationY = (rawY - mMinRawY) - mQuickReturnHeight;
                    if (translationY > 0) {
                        translationY = 0;
                        mMinRawY = rawY - mQuickReturnHeight;
                    }

                    if (rawY > 0) {
                        mState = STATE_ONSCREEN;
                        translationY = rawY;
                    }

                    if (translationY < -mQuickReturnHeight) {
                        mState = STATE_OFFSCREEN;
                        mMinRawY = rawY;
                    }
                    break;
                }

                /** this can be used if the build is below honeycomb **/
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, translationY,
                            translationY);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                    anim.setDuration(0);
                    mQuickReturnView.startAnimation(anim);
                } else {
                    mQuickReturnView.setTranslationY(translationY);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }
        });
        rlMain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
        rlMain.addView(view);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

Now it showing error in `mListView = (QuickReturnListView) getListView();`

```
02-13 21:23:03.389: E/AndroidRuntime(26896): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quickreturnlistwithactivity/com.example.quickreturnlistwithactivity.QuickReturnActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView cannot be cast to com.example.quickreturnlistwithactivity.QuickReturnListView
02-13 21:23:03.389: E/AndroidRuntime(26896): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView cannot be cast to com.example.quickreturnlistwithactivity.QuickReturnListView
02-13 21:23:03.389: E/AndroidRuntime(26896):    at com.example.quickreturnlistwithactivity.QuickReturnActivity.onCreate(QuickReturnActivity.java:67)
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: My main problem is in trying to make exact same listview given in the video using activity. In the sample code it using fragments .

Comment: @MD I know i am not quite clear , but if you go through the example you will understand my problem.

Comment: i am implement the same with Activity,

Comment: @MD In my implentation it's showing `java.lang.StackOverflowError` in the line `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);`

Comment: try this way `LayoutInflater inflater  = youractivity.this.getLayoutInflater();` or `inflater = (LayoutInflater) youractivity.this.
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47425/discussion-between-kunu-and-m-d)

Answer (score 0):

Just think about each tab as separate application, that have the same view. The only difference is witch tab is selected.

Your only disadvantage will be performance, as activity is much heavier process than fragment.
Also if you would like to share data between activities it will be harder than using fragments.

Also you may find [this](http://blog.quentinrousseau.fr/index.php/2013/06/activity-transition-animations-like-the-vine-android-application/) tutorial interesting. It show small example of activities transitions.

Comment: Can you please suggest me if I want only one activity i.e let's say `DefaultFragment` from the example. So how can I convert that into Activity.

Comment: @Kunu you got full source code of that in the tutorial you found. How possibly I can help you more than that?!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have the markup looks like:

```
<your_package_path.QuickReturnListView
```